# How to show php file output on Page where from it is called?

Tags: javascript, php

I have webpage on which i run a php file by javascript as given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bhs = document.createElement('script');
    var bhs_id = "yvw3lwc1tnvqfh4k4k4hisossew";
    bhs.src = "//example.com/insert.php?site=" + bhs_id + "";    
    document.head.appendChild(bhs);
document.write("<span id='calc'></span>");
</script>
```

This JavaScript successfully insert data into insert.php file and then send to database. Besides i want to show one variable value generated in insert.php file in span id calc on a webpage where from above JavaScript is executed. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give me details

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: can you provide me some simple example or related stackoverflow thread?

Answer (score 0):

It´s better use AJAX:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var bhs_id = "yvw3lwc1tnvqfh4k4k4hisossew";   
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     alert('OK!');
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "//example.com/insert.php?site=" + bhs_id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp